# Pasar el valor de select al caption del datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

Tengo el siguiente problema, tengo un `select` y necesito tomar el valor seleccionado y colocarlo como parte del `caption` de un `datatable` les adjunto código del `select` que se carga con una consulta:

```
<div class='col-md-4' style="">
        <label>Seleccione Destino</label>
        <select class='form-control' name='destino' id='destino' >
         <option value="">Selecciona Area destino</option>
         <?php
          $query_area = mysqli_query($conn, "select id_area, area from areas 
                 where area <> 'Auditoría' order by area asc");
                 while ($rw = mysqli_fetch_array($query_area)) {
               ?>
           <option value="<?php echo $rw['id_area']; ?>"><?php echo 
                $rw['area'];
                $rw['id_area']; ?></option>

           <?php

              }

              ?>
       </select>
     </div>
```

**Adjunto el `script` con el que cargo el `datatable` haciendo una consulta**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 function listar(){

 var destino = document.getElementById('destino').value;

 var table = $("#auditoria").DataTable({

  "destroy": true,
  "order": [0, 'desc'],
    "ajax": {
        "method": "POST",
        "url": "data/getarea.php",
        "data": function (d) {
            return $.extend({}, d, {
                "idarea": $('#idarea').val()
            });
        }
    },
    "columns": [{
            "data": "id"
        }, {
            "data": "nombre"
        }, {
            "data": "marca"
        }, {
            "data": "proveedor"
        }, {
            "data": "inicial"
        }, {
            "data": "fecha"
        }, {

                "data": "expediente"
            }, {
                "data": "actual"
            }
        ],
      }

</script>
```

**Adjunto el `table` que tengo para los datos de la consulta**

```
<table id="auditoria" class="table table-hover table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
          <caption> listado de Productos </caption>
          <thead >
           <tr>
            <th>Código</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Marca</th>
            <th>Proveedor</th>
            <th>Cantidad Inicial</th>
            <th>Fecha</th>
            <th>Expediente</th>
            <th>Sotck actual</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
  </table>
```

**Adjunto imagen de la pagina:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Perdon no puedo editar el codigo del script, pero si funciona y carga el datatable

Comment: Deberias agregar tu HTML.

Comment: Lo que quieres es que cambie el `caption` cada vez que se cambie el `select`?

Comment: Si esta agregado el table y en el <caption> deberia poder poner el valor del select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para cambiar el valor del `<caption>` te recomiendo dejarlo creado en el código html dentro de la tabla y asignarle un id (en este caso "ctexto"):

```
<caption id="ctexto"></caption>
```

Luego al ejecutar la función listar y obtener el valor del `<select>` ponerlo en el `<caption>` con `innerHTML`:

```
document.getElementById("ctexto").innerHTML=destino;
```

Aunque imagino que el texto que quieres mostrar dentro del `<caption>` no es el valor sino el texto del `<select>`, te dejo el código funcionando para ambos casos (es ejecutable, puedes ver el resultado en la pagina, selecciona un opción y haz click en "listar"):

```js
function listar(){

  var combo = document.getElementById("destino");
  texto = combo.options[combo.selectedIndex].text;
  var destino = combo.value;
  document.getElementById("ctexto").innerHTML=destino+'-'+texto;
  
  var table = $("#auditoria").DataTable({

  "destroy": true,
  "order": [0, 'desc'],
    "ajax": {
        "method": "POST",
        "url": "data/getarea.php",
        "data": function (d) {
            return $.extend({}, d, {
                "idarea": $('#idarea').val()
            });
        }
    },
    "columns": [{
            "data": "id"
        }, {
            "data": "nombre"
        }, {
            "data": "marca"
        }, {
            "data": "proveedor"
        }, {
            "data": "inicial"
        }, {
            "data": "fecha"
        }, {

                "data": "expediente"
            }, {
                "data": "actual"
            }
        ],
      });
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <div class='col-md-4' style="">
        <label>Seleccione Destino</label>
        <select class='form-control' name='destino' id='destino' >
         <option value="">Selecciona Area destino</option>
           <option value="1">Area 1</option>
           <option value="2">Area 2</option>
       </select>
       <button onclick="listar()">Listar</button>
     </div>
    <hr>
<table id="auditoria" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <caption id="ctexto" >Listado de Productos</caption>
        <thead >
           <tr>
            <th>Código</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Marca</th>
            <th>Proveedor</th>
            <th>Cantidad Inicial</th>
            <th>Fecha</th>
            <th>Expediente</th>
            <th>Sotck actual</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            
            </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            
        </tfoot>
    </table>
    
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
```

Espero te sea de utilidad, saludos.

Comment: Excelente!!, funciono Muchas Gracias a todos... Gracias ...

Comment: @Julio de nada.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agregar el caption de la siguiente manera

```js
var myvar = "This is dynamic data"
$('#jquery_table').append('<caption style="caption-side: top-right"> myvar</caption>');
```

O en este caso:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

 function listar(){

 var destino = document.getElementById('destino').value;
 
 $('#auditoria').append('<caption style="caption-side:    top-right">'+destino+'</caption>');
 
 var table = $("#auditoria").DataTable({

  "destroy": true,
  "order": [0, 'desc'],
    "ajax": {
        "method": "POST",
        "url": "data/getarea.php",
        "data": function (d) {
            return $.extend({}, d, {
                "idarea": $('#idarea').val()
            });
        }
    },
    "columns": [{
            "data": "id"
        }, {
            "data": "nombre"
        }, {
            "data": "marca"
        }, {
            "data": "proveedor"
        }, {
            "data": "inicial"
        }, {
            "data": "fecha"
        }, {

                "data": "expediente"
            }, {
                "data": "actual"
            }
        ],
      }

</script>
```

Consulta el siguiente enlace https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/51231/caption-for-the-datatable#Comment_137480

Saludos

Comment: Si, necesito que cambie el caption cuando hace la funcion listar() que es un click de un boton pero me trae el número id no el nombre del area ??

Comment: Jonathan, gracias funciona pero trae el valor numerico, es decir el id del select y lo va agregando en el caption del datatable uno debajo del otro cuando llamo la funcion listar()

Comment: Perdon, Como puedo agregar una imagen de pantalla para mostrar el resultado...

Comment: Agregue una imagen de pantalla de como queda el caption, el id del select se repite y no me muestra el valor del select